# python iterate over a multi level dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a data-structure with a three level dictionary containing DataFrames. I am trying to iterate through the data frames and apply operations to the dataframes. What I'm actually trying to do - change stock prices in the dataframes to 21 day returns.

I can't even get the iteration to work:

```
for dte in df_usage['SPX']['Prices'].items():
    df_usage['SPX']['Prices'][dte] =  df_usage['SPX']['Prices'][dte].pct_change(lookback)
```

Returns:

```
  File "<ipython-input-69-fce8ba1b2a72>", line 2, in <module>
    df_usage['SPX']['Prices'][dte] =  df_usage['SPX']['Prices'][dte].pct_change(lookback)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1492, in __hash__
    ' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))

TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Have looked over many similar questions but haven't been able to figure it out - I'm very much a novice. Thank you very much.

[edited question]

Comment: Well this error tells me that `df_usage['SPX']['Prices']` is an `int` already, i.e. it's a number and not a dataframe.

Comment: I apologise! I'm an idiot - set them to zero when messing around. the actual error is: TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Answer (score 1):

The answer was:

```
for dte in df_usage['SPX']['Prices'].keys():
    df_usage['SPX']['Prices'][dte] =  df_usage['SPX']['Prices'][dte].pct_change(lookback)
```

I was using .items() when I should have been using .keys() - as in each of my dataframes was an item referred to by the date, which was the key!